# ASP.NET MVC Delete function external link path give Error

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Hello i want to delete database item.when ı do delete if the data has local path there is no problem fine work.

**But**

İf the file has an external link it will give an error.

**Get error :**

> System.Web.HttpException: '' https:
>   /www.really-learn-english.com/image-files/letter-h.png 'is not a valid
>   virtual path.'

Check Please:
1. [Database and Scnerio Photo!](https://ibb.co/gJFxzy) 2. [Browser Screen!](https://ibb.co/b0cwRd)

**Code**

```
//Delete Images START
var getoldimages = db.DergiFotoes.Where(s => s.DergiID == getmkl.DergiID && 
s.Module == WebUtil.MAKALE_MODULE).ToList();
  if (getoldimages.Count > 0)
     {
  foreach (var item in getoldimages)
     {
     string fullPath = HttpContext.Current.Request.MapPath(item.Ad);
  if (System.IO.File.Exists(fullPath))
     {
        System.IO.File.Delete(fullPath);
     }
     }
        db.DergiFotoes.RemoveRange(getoldimages);
        db.SaveChanges();
     }
//Delete Images END
     getmkl.Sil = true;
     db.SaveChanges();
     return true;
```

- **NOTE**: My purpose is not to delete the data in the remote web site. I
     just want to delete the data row in the database table, even if user an
     external link is used for data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot get virtual path for remote file using HttpContext.Current.Request.MapPath. This method is used to get full path of files stored locally in your ASP.NET application.

Also you can't delete files from remote server in this way (assuming you don't have write access to that server).

If you need to deleted files from website and it's yours, then consider implementing RESTful API there and use DELETE HTTP method.

Update: if you need to clean up your database - just delete record that points to remote file, without any checking. If it's local file - use File. Delete as you shown in code listing.

I hope that helped.

Comment: My purpose is not to delete the data in the remote web site. Even if the user uses an external link I just want to delete the in table data row. when inserting data in database some time user use can upload images with external link any web site or some time use local image upload for data So Question has current code how can ı manage it?

Comment: The solution is very easy to see. Why don't you check the content of `item.Ad` before calling `MapPath`? If `item.Ad` contains http or https, don't call `MapPath`.